# SQL identify records which occur more than certain months

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, having

I'm trying to identify members who have more than 4 months of claims for any single procedure code. Below is the SQL code that I tried. I'm not sure if that is right.

**Table**

```
+-------------+---------------+-----------+------------+
| ServiceDate | ProcedureCode | MemberId  | Claim_Nbr  |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+------------+
| 2018-01-15  | K800          | 364882903 | 1600235465 |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+------------+
| 2018-02-15  | K800          | 364882903 | 1607478399 |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+------------+
| 2018-01-15  | K800          | 388299399 | 4589992948 |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+------------+
| 2018-03-15  | K800          | 364882903 | 1600489300 |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+------------+
| 2018-04-15  | K800          | 364882903 | 1600388289 |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+------------+
| 2018-05-15  | K800          | 364882903 | 1600028848 |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+------------+
| 2018-06-15  | K800          | 364882903 | 1600894889 |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+------------+
| 2018-07-15  | K800          | 364882903 | 1600023884 |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+------------+
| 2018-07-15  | K800          | 364882903 | 1600934888 |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+------------+
| 2018-02-15  | K800          | 388299399 | 3774999999 |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+------------+
| 2018-03-15  | K800          | 388299399 | 9498378489 |
+-------------+---------------+-----------+------------+
```

SQL Code

```
SELECT ProcedureCode, MemberId FROM CLAIMS
GROUP BY ProcedureCode
HAVING SUM(Month(ServiceDate))>4
```

[SQL example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7b933/1)

Comment: Please define what a "month of claims" is.

Comment: If a member has a claim/claims for more than 4 months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want members where the procedure code appears in more than 4 months, you can use `count(distinct)`:

```
select memberId, procedureCode
from claims
group by memberId, procedureCode
having count(distinct year(ServiceDate) * 100 + month(ServiceDate)) > 4;
```

Comment: Why are you multiplying by 100?

Comment: @shockwave . . . SQL Server doesn't support multiple arguments to `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.  I could multiply by 12 instead, by YYYYMM makes sense as a format, even for a number.